# android dynamic 2D drawing on a Canvas

Tags: android, graphics, 2d

I'm trying to understand how to dynamically generate 2D graphics on Android. I haven't been able to find an example on the web of someone doing this.

My example below randomly draws 1000 lines of random colors. I'd like to see all of the lines being drawn, but I don't see anything until the setContentView() call (at which point all of the lines are already drawn).

I've tried many permutations, including moving the setContentView() to before the draw() call, and adding ourView.invalidate() inside the for loop, but in every case the screen stays white until after all the lines are drawn.

If someone can point to an example of this working, I'd be happy to go research it and add the correct answer here myself.

```
package com.example.graphicsdemo;
+imports

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView ourView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        draw();
        setContentView(ourView);
    }
    public void draw() {
        Bitmap blankBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(600,600,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(blankBitmap);
        ourView = new ImageView(this);
        ourView.setImageBitmap(blankBitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Random random = new Random();

        for(int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++) {
            paint.setColor(Color.argb(255, random.nextInt(255), random.nextInt(255), random.nextInt(255)));
            canvas.drawLine(random.nextInt(600), random.nextInt(600), random.nextInt(600), random.nextInt(600), paint);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this Example will help :
first make your own View and lets call it DynamicView :

```
import java.util.Random;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class DynamicView extends View {
    int i = 0;

    public DynamicView(Context context) {
        super(context);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Random random = new Random();
        paint.setColor(Color.argb(255, random.nextInt(255),
                random.nextInt(255), random.nextInt(255)));
        canvas.drawLine(random.nextInt(600), random.nextInt(600),
                random.nextInt(600), random.nextInt(600), paint);

        if (i < 1000) {
            i++;
            invalidate();
        }
    }

}
```

this view will invalidate a 1000 time after each draw

now here is your main activity's onCreate method :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        DynamicView myView = new DynamicView(this);
        setContentView(myView);
    }
```

as simple as this.

**Responding to your question** this is a better code and more complicated but still easy to understand 
All we have to do is to draw the lines on a bitmap and then draw that bitmap on the view, so the bitmap will not change and will have all previous drawn lines and still draw on it

now here is the updated code :

**DynamicView**

```
import java.util.Random;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class DynamicView extends View {
    int i = 0;
    Bitmap frame ;
    Canvas frameDrawer;
    Rect bounds;
    Paint paint ;
    Random random ;
    int width , height;

    public DynamicView(Context context ,int width ,int height) {
        super(context);

        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        frame = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,height,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        frameDrawer = new Canvas(frame);
        bounds = new Rect(0 , 0, width,height);
        //this initialization will make the frameDrawer draw on the frame bitmap

        //always avoid allocating new objects in the draw method to optimize the performance 
        paint = new Paint();
        random = new Random();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


        paint.setColor(Color.argb(255, random.nextInt(255),
                random.nextInt(255), random.nextInt(255)));
        //instead of drawing on the view canvas draw on the frame bitmap
        frameDrawer.drawLine(random.nextInt(width), random.nextInt(height),
                random.nextInt(width), random.nextInt(height), paint);
        // and then draw the bitmap on the view canvas
        canvas.drawBitmap(frame, null, bounds , null);

        if (i < 1000) {
            i++;
            invalidate();
        }
    }

}
```

now the new thing in the MainActivity is that now we can take controll over the view drawing bounds but still not the view's bounds which take all the screen space (if you want to adjust the view's bounds just implement the onLayout method and enter your value's )

**MainActivity**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        DynamicView myView = new DynamicView(this,320,480);
        setContentView(myView);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer, and actually helped me understand the onDraw()/invalidate() paradigm. Thank you for that. I see that I omitted something in my question - I want new lines to be *added* to the view, such that the display is the aggregate of all lines drawn. When I ran your example, the result was 1000 independent lines each drawn on a pristine white backdrop.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. It's working beautifully.  Now off to learn more about why it works (i.e., about bitmaps).